# How to deal with Struct having different json key than json response

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a struct `VideoInfo` that has a key in it called `embedCode`. The API I am querying returns the embed code as `embed_code`. During unmarshalling the response how do I ensure `embed_code` goes into `embedCode`?

Also is there an easy way to take a large json string and automatically turn it into a struct, or can one only use a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to remapping the field names use the corresponding annotation in the structure declaration:

```
type VideoInfo struct {
    EmbedCode string `json:"embed_code"`
}
```

The marshaller/un-marshaller will only process public field, so you need to capitalise the field name.

With respect to converting the whole structure, yes it is easy. Declare an instance to un-marshal into and pass a reference to the `json.Unmarshal` method (from a test):

```
data, _ := json.Marshal(request)

var resp response.VideoInfo
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &resp); err != nil {
    t.Errorf("unexpected error, %v", err)
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, so im glad you confirmed this was the right way. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

At first, struct's field must be start from capital letter to be public. So you need something like that:

```
type VideoInfo struct {
    EmbedCode string `json:"embed_code"`
}
```

And look at [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for more info.